Are pointers of different types compatible?
I'm trying to determine if two structs are compatible. In my case, it's not clear to me if pointers of different types are considered compatible. In the following example, are structs t1 and t2 compatible?
typedef struct string {
  size_t len;
  char   val[]; // flexible array member
} string;

struct t1 {
  const char *name;
};

struct t2 {
  string *name;
};

Since they are both pointers (and not pointers to functions), they have the same size and alignment (at least for this platform), which is a prerequisite to being compatible. But I do not understand all the other rules well enough to know if these are compatible. Knowing if they are compatible factors into things like the common initial sequence for unions, casting pointers to compatible types, etc.
My guess is that no, they are not compatible. I would guess the pointers would have to point to the same or compatible types, and this is neither.

The term "layout compatible" does not appear in the language spec. Are you asking about the concept of compatible type (which relates to all data types, not just structure types)?

I don't have access to the C standard. I was looking at excerpts people have posted, and also at draft C++ standards (which I know are not quite the same on this detail). I believe that yes, that's what I am looking for. Question edited accordingly.

The fact you asked previously about layout compatibility suggests you may want to use struct t1 in place of struct t2. If so, then asking about compatibility is also the wrong question to ask. If your C implementation uses the same representation for const char * as it does for string * and struct t1 and struct t2 are the same size (the compiler does not add any padding, which would be weird), then you can interpret one as the other type, and a way to do this is to memcpy the bytes of one into the bytes of another. A good compiler may optimize this well, eliding the copy…

… That resolves the problem of reinterpreting one pointer/structure as the other type. There would remain the problem of aliasing the pointed-to types. To resolve that, you would have to provide further information about what you seek to do.

See C11 §6.2.7 Compatible types and composite types.  It's intense reading, but the three structure types are all distinct and each is incompatible with the other two types.

Layout-compatibility in C++ has little relation with compatibible types in C. If you meant to ask about properties akin to layout-compatibility in C++, your current wording is probably asking the wrong question. IIRC, "Common initial sequence" is also unique to C++.

I found a draft of C23. common initial sequence does appear there, see 6.5.2.3.

Note: The question has been edited. This answer speaks to questions as they appeared when they were quoted here.
Size, Alignment, and Representation of Pointers

Since they are both pointers (and not pointers to functions), they have the same size and alignment, which is a prerequisite.

This premise is false. Nothing in the C standard requires different types of pointers to have the same size or alignment requirements except, per C 2018 6.2.5 28:

A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.

Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements.

All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.

All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.


The paragraph ends with the explicit statement:

Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

Compatibility

I'm trying to determine if two structs are compatible. In my case, it's not clear to me if pointers of different types are considered compatible. In the following example, are structs t1 and t2 compatible?

The question previously asked about layout compatibility. Layout is not defined in the C standard but is generally understood to how bytes represent a value in a type and are sequenced in memory. Now the question asks about compatibility. Compatibility is a technical term in the C standard.
The above asks two questions about compatibility: Are pointers of different types compatible? Are structures t1 and t2 compatible?
In the C standard, compatible generally means that two types can be completed to be the same type. For example, an array of an unknown number of int and an array of 4 int are compatible.
The way the C standard specifies compatibility is constructive: Two types are compatible if and only if there is a rule saying they are. If there is no such rule, the types are not compatible. C 2018 6.2.7 1 specifies the requirements for two structures to be compatible. Essentially, each definition of a structure is a different type, and two different structure types in the same translation unit are not compatible. Therefore struct t1 and struct t2 are not compatible. (6.2.7 1 provides that two structure types defined in different translation units are compatible if, in essence, they are identically defined.)
C 2018 6.7.6.1 2 specifies the rule for pointer types to be compatible: “For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.” For the pointer types in the question, const char *name and string *name, the types they point (const char and string) to are not compatible, and therefore the pointer types are not compatible.

You focused on one bit that isn't necessarily a deal-breaker for the question. Assume for a moment that the pointers have the same size/align for the platform. Or alternatively, the struct t1 uses a pointer to a struct cstr { const char val[]; } so that both t1 and t2 are now both pointers to structures.  Are the structs t1 and t2 then compatible, or not?

@LeviMorrison: I am editing the answer. However, I answered the question as it was posed. When you tag a question [language-lawyer] and do not specify an implementation, it is a question about the C standard. Different pointer types are not required to be “layout compatible.” Further, it is improper to edit a question after it has been answered in a way that renders answers inapplicable. Participants in Stack Overflow would be entitled to roll back your question to a previous version. If you want to ask a different question than you asked, the proper way is to enter a new question.

I understand that these are more sensitive than other questions, but the question was clearly about compatibility from the title and body, and not about alignment of pointer types. Your response from the beginning could have been "if the pointers do not share size/align, then they are definitely not compatible, else..." My edit makes no impact to the validity of your answer.

@LeviMorrison: No, your question was not clearly about compatibility. Compatibility is a specific term in the C standard with technical requirements, and your question about “layout compatibility” did not touch on compatibility. In C, even if two types have exactly the same size, alignment requirements, and layout in bytes, that does not make them compatible.

Thanks for your help. It's clear the codebase that prompted this question has rampant abuse of unions, pointer conversions, and more.


I'm trying to determine if two structs are compatible.

The term originally used in the question was "layout-compatible", which does not appear in the language spec.  The spec does attribute considerable significance to the idea of compatible type, but this relates to all types, not just structure types.  Important to this distinction is that although you can conceptualize C's type compatibility rules as relating in part to the layout of members and padding inside structures, identical layout is not sufficient for structure types to be compatible with each other.

it's not clear to me if pointers of different types are considered compatible.

Only if they are identically qualified and point to compatible types.
The primary rule is C17 6.2.7/1:

Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional
rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described
in 6.7.2 for type specifiers,

(each enumerated type is compatible with an implementation-defined integer type)

in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers,

(the order of type qualifiers is not significant for type compatibility)

and in
6.7.6 for declarators.

(specific provisions for several different type categories; most relevant here is "For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers
to compatible types." (C17 6.7.6.1/2))

Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible
if [...]

Each structure type declaration declares a distinct type, and there is no provision making any pair of distinct structure types declared in the same translation unit compatible with each other, no matter what their tags, members, or member order.  Thus, your struct t1 and struct t2 are not compatible, regardless of the compatibility of types const char * and string *.  Giving their respective name members identical type would not fix that.
Your original "layout-compatible" idea may have been related to the next part of the rule:

their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one
is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag.
If both are completed anywhere within their respective translation
units, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall
be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each
pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types; if
one member of the pair is declared with an alignment specifier, the
other is declared with an equivalent alignment specifier; and if one
member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared with
the same name. For two structures, corresponding members shall be
declared in the same order. For two structures or unions,
corresponding bit-fields shall have the same widths. For two
enumerations, corresponding members shall have the same values.

(emphasis added)
This is the relevant provision when you declare a structure type in a header, and then include that header in different translation units.  You don't have the same structure type in those different units, but you do have compatible types.
You also say:

Since they are both pointers (and not pointers to functions), they have the same size and alignment (at least for this platform), which is a prerequisite to being compatible.

struct t1 and struct t2 are not pointer types.  They are structure types, which, in general, bear little resemblance to pointers.  Now, pointers to different structure types do all have the same representation and alignment requirements (C17 6.2.5/28), but the spec does not relate this with type compatibility.
Also, pointers to different union types all have the same representation and alignment as each other, pointers to differently-qualified versions of compatible types have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other, and pointers to void have the same representation and alignment requirement as pointers to character types.  Other than that, the spec is explicit:

Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

That last would apply to your string * and const char *, so not only are those types not compatible, they are not even required to have the same representation (including size) or alignment.

So... struct t1 { int a; } and struct t2 { int a; } are already not compatible. However, one can be interpreted as the other with proper memcpy and such, and not through a pointer cast. Is all that correct?

@LeviMorrison It seems you are actually looking for things related to type-punning. t1 and t2 are not compatible types in the C standard, but I doubt it's actually what you are looking for. Pointer cast between t1* and t2* violates the strict-aliasing rule and is illegal. memcpy between t1 and t2 is legal, so is type-punning via a union in C (but not C++).

Type compatibility is important for unions, see 6.5.2.3 "One special guarantee is made to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members."

@LeviMorrison, yes, struct t1 and struct t2 are already incompatible, regardless of their members.  Yes, in practice, if the members all match up properly, it is possible to memcpy the representation of one of those into an object of the other type, and read out the destination object correctly.  That is one viable way to reinterpret one as the other.  Yes, type punning via pointer cast in most cases violates the "strict aliasing rule", C17 6.5/7, and therefore has undefined behavior (but the casts themselves are ok).

@LeviMorrison, yes, (in C) unions provide another way to reinterpret part or even all of an object of one type as an object of a different type, subject to some limitations.  You seem to have found the relevant provisions.


they have the same size and alignment,

The 2 pointer types can have the same size and layout on OP's machine, yet that is not certain across all compliant C implementations.
Highly portable code does not rely on same size.

Will have the same alignment requirement is a near certainty in practice, but not guaranteed by the spec.

@JohnBollinger Agree'd
